# How can I set up branch.io for dynamic links

Tags: cordova, ionic2, branch.io

Sorry if this question seems newbie as this is my 1st time using branch.io. I have integrated the SDK onto my app and tested the link. However, I'm stuck at the next step - create links.

I am trying to set up branch.io so that my users can share the contents using the social share plug-ins. The contents are dynamically created from the CMS.

Will some kind souls help point me to the correct direction?
P.S, I have read all the documentations provided and the more I read, the more confused I've got

Answer (score 1):

Amruta from [Branch.io](http://branch.io) here:

It is very easy to create Branch links within your app and add the dynamically generated content to the link parameters.
Branch also has a default share sheet which can be integrated into your app to give your users the ability to share the links.

You can check out our documentation [here](https://dev.branch.io/marketing-channels/content-sharing/guide/cordova/).

You just need to add the following code to your app:

1. Create a BranchUniversalObject containing details about the content that is being shared.

var branchUniversalObj = null;

```
Branch.createBranchUniversalObject({
  canonicalIdentifier: 'monster/12345',
  title: 'Meet Mr. Squiggles',
  contentDescription: 'Your friend Josh has invited you to meet his awesome monster, Mr. Squiggles!',
  contentImageUrl: 'https://example.com/monster-pic-12345.png',
  contentMetadata: {
    'userId': '12345',
    'userName': 'Josh',
    'monsterName': 'Mr. Squiggles'
  }
}).then(function (newBranchUniversalObj) {
  branchUniversalObj = newBranchUniversalObj;
  console.log(newBranchUniversalObj);
});
```

2. Use the `sharesheet()` method with your Branch universal object to show Branch's custom share sheet. You can add analytics tags such as `channel`,`campaign` etc. as a parameter.

   ```
   branchUniversalObj.showShareSheet({
     // put your link properties here
     "feature" : "share",
     "channel" : "facebook"
   }, {
     // put your control parameters here
     "$desktop_url" : "http://desktop-url.com",
   });
   ```